# Volley: Is there a way to check if a request is pending or in progress?

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

Pretty straight forward:

Is there a way to tell if a Volley request is currently pending/ongoing?

Of course I can track its state manually through the different callbacks but is there a better way?

Comment: http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

this blog is all about volley variation but i think you can get it manually there is no builtin callback in it

Comment: I can't even do it by subclassing Request<T>! There is just no way to tell when are added to a queue, when are you being dispatched etc...

Comment: it's a async request. we just check it out by callback but if don't have any then we will manually do such things

Answer (score -1):

The only way that I can think of right now is to subclass RequestQueue, and expose the simplest method ever:

```
public boolean contains(Request<?> request) {
    return mCurrentRequests.contains(request);
}
```

But then I'll have a hard time creating and configuring my Queue since I can't call `Volley.newRequestQueue(Context)`

If there won't be a better answer I'll go with this one... :(

Comment: but you are doing it manually as i mentioned above in my comment

Comment: The request being a-sync has nothing to do with that. I've seen many frameworks where you can just ask a request "Are you currently executing?" I expected that volley will have something similar